# MVC.NET SessionState Attribute vs SetSessionStateBehavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5, session-state

I have a strange problem here. I would like to get some thoughts about it.

Our project has some performance problems. The reason for the problems is the session block mechanism of mvc.net. Many requests come from one source with the same session id and the mvc pipeline queues them.

So we decided to change our project to sessionless. But for some reason, our project should behave sessionless depending on a flag. At this point I've decided to change the session behaviour on the global.asax Application_BeginRequest method, and add this method:

```
HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled);
```

After adding this code, I tested and yes the session is null but requests were still queued. The performance problem continues. Then I moved the above code to a httpmodule.PostMapRequestHandler event. When I tested this, the session was again null but the queue problem was still there. After this failure, I added the below attribute to my base controller.

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```

Eureka ! Session is null and the queue problem went away. My project now runs very fast.

This worked, but it should depend on a flag. So I have to put #if preprocessor condition here, that I do not want to.

What is the difference between these codes ? Why do SessionState attribute and SetSessionStateBehavior behave differently ? And is there any other solution for this situation ?

Thank you.

Comment: The performance issues are most likely associated with session state blocking. This is just a guess, but it may be that when you use `SetSessionStateBehavior` to dynamically set the session state access, the blocking determination might be made at some earlier point in the request handling process? [This article](https://abhijitjana.net/2011/01/15/programmatically-changing-session-state-behavior-in-asp-net-4-0/) talks a little about some of the relevant events in the request cycle.

Comment: RANT: It's really a shame that Microsoft has never copied php's solution: `session_write_close`. It seems so obvious that you might need write access to session state initially but not for the full request cycle. Having a mechanism to write and close session state mid-request (and thus also release any blocks for other requests from that user) is really handy.

Comment: @David784 thank you for your response. I could not find any solution for this situation. I had to solve it by defining build configuration and putting SessionState attribute.